Buck double output stage LC filter
I am trying to design a buck with a double output stage filter like this one from this AN:

It is written from this AN the second output filter will have a negligeable effect on stability if the double poles of the second stage filter are not included in the control loop.

So I tried to see it on SIMPLIS and here is the result:
Note: We do not see the inductor of the 1st filter (4.7 µH as it is included in a component). Here are the bode plot without 2nd output filter:

Here are bode plots with different value of double poles. There is no effect on stability. It affects the crossover frequency but If I add a resistor (R10) to attenuate the resonance of the 2nd output filter. There is no effect at all, it tends to increase the phase margin. What is the recommendation of TI? I may do something wrong?

Here are the results with an attenuation resistors:

Note: If there is no inductor, the crossover frequency will be around 15 kHz. The 2nd output filter has no effect on the crossover frequency if it is attenuated.
Thank you and have a nice day.

What do you mean "attenuated"? Adjusting the value of R10?

Yes ! I will make an edit

...To what values? | You say "no effect on stability" yet the solid red curve is clearly crossing 180° at above unity gain (~10kHz), surely this indicates runaway oscillation?  I assume the first plot is the case with R10 ~ infinity, but then why are there three curves? Please label all plots, including respective component value or circuit changes. | What is your question? -- "What is the recommendation of TI?" -- we cannot answer this here; but you can ask their help forum at https://e2e.ti.com/ and copy back a satisfactory self-answer here if you like.

@TimWilliams Actually you re right, if we take a look with a nyquist plot it appears that the gain and phase margin are lower if the filter is not correclty damped as you mention it. TI may consider a global case, i.e if you place an LC filter with frequency resonance superior to the crossover frequency of the converter, if it is not correctly damp it will not affect in any case the stability of the converter. However it seems that you can place an LC filter with a lower resonant frequency without affecting stability if it is correclty damp
